# How can i chose my icon based on a string

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a lot of strings whos' names are those of icons. If I try to create and Icon with a string as name

```dart
Icon(
   Icons._transactionType
)
```

I get 'the getter _transactionType is not defined for for the class 'Icons''.

That is all the ideas I had so far, and also the flutter docs for icon and icons didn't help.

As of now i have hardcoded the icons in, but since i am now storing them in .json, i can only save them in strings, and i want to avoid a method that goes through all icons and choses the one i need.

Here you see it working now, and i want to get the icon istead of with 'Icons.train' with 'Icons._transactionType'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a map

```
Map<String, IconData> iconMapping = {
 'train' : Icons.train,
 'airplane' : Icons.airplanemode_active,
 ...
};
```

and while using, instead of `Icon(Icons._transactionType)` use `Icon(iconMapping[_transactionType])`

Comment: while this is the kind of solution i tried to avoid i still think it is the best one. i will do this then, thank you!